# How to Copy a matrix into Ms Word Table without loop with C#

Tags: c#, excel, string, ms-word

I did copy a whole string [4273,11] into Word but it takes so much time by looping and inserting each cell every time. What I want to do is copy a whole string [4273,11] directly into the **MS Word** **table**. If there is also a way to copy the content of an Excel worksheet to MS Word I will be grateful because it will solve the problem any way.

```
public void WriteContent(string[,] array, Word.Table oDoc)
{
// This is where I fill the Excel worksheet with the string [4273,11] array

Range range = (Range)m_worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
range = range.get_Resize(4273, 11);
// Assign the 2-d array to the Excel Range
range.set_Value(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, array);

//This is Where I want to Paste the Excel "range" into the word document
}
```

Comment: It might help if you could post some of your code to see what is happenening. Possibly it needs just a bit of tweaking to make it run more efficient.

Comment: public void WriteContent(string[,] array, Word.Table oDoc)

        {

            Range range = (Range)m_worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
            range = range.get_Resize(4273, 11);
            // Assign the 2-d array to the Excel Range
            range.set_Value(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, array);

// This is Where I want to Paste the Excel "range" into the word document
           

        }

Comment: edited question with this code

Comment: I did it. is there a way to do the same way for Word table. If not could I paste the range content into word doc

Answer (score 1):

You can copy and paste between office applications, but that is a very large range to copy, so you will need some delay or check. This reply is from a knowledge of Office, not c#.

```
range.Copy();
_wordApp.Selection.Paste();
```

Comment: Than you . I already did it, the issue is how to select a specific range so I did this   "m_Worksheet.get_Range("A1", "K5000").Copy();"

Comment: This `range = range.get_Resize(4273, 11);` and the next line means your range is already selected.

Answer (score 0):

Than you . I already did it, the issue is how to select a specific range so I did this

`m_Worksheet.get_Range("A1", "K5000").Copy();`

`This range = range.get_Resize(4273, 11);`

and the next line means your range is already selected.